# Cannot use a returned value

Tags: python

New to python, probably a dumb question. It's saying the "addAns" in the last line is undefined. How do I get it to use the value from the add function

```
def add (addL):
    c = 0
    while c < 4:
        x = input("Type a number to add. " )
        c += 1
        addL.append(x)
        if x == "end":
            c += 5
            addL.remove("end")    
    addStep = [int(i) for i in addL]
    addAns = sum(addStep)
    return addAns
userIn = input("What function would you like to perform? ")
if userIn == 'add':
    add(addL)
    print(addAns)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should assign the output of the function:

```
if userIn == 'add':
    addAns = add(addL)
    print(addAns)
```

It doesn't need to be the same name, the scopes are independent:

```
if userIn == 'add':
    output = add(addL)
    print(output)
```

You can also directly use the output in `print`:

```
if userIn == 'add':
    print(add(addL))
```

Comment: Exactly so.  The `return addAns` in the function returns the value but not the name - it's up to you to capture that value.